# increase the size of App in android

Tags: android

I have an Ardino Comic,Which is In PDf Form,I split it and convert it 
into the PNG form now I am  calling  this image one by one and also 
fliping this page,but it takes only five pages and give an error like 
memory problem.So how can I increase the memory of App in tab.Please 
help me.

is it possible

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't increase the size of application. This is happen because the limited memory size of heap. So the alternate way is recycle your objects on which you load the images, or release them after use of one by one. so it help you.

EDIT: this works in my case.

```
    try
{
   if(bm!=null)
     {
        bm.recycle();   //here we recycle the bitmap object for further use.
                               // you can also use System.gc();
        bm=null;
      }

   InputStream stream;
   stream = new FileInputStream("your image file path");

   bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, null);

   try
     {
       stream.close();
       stream=null;
      }
   catch (IOException e)
    {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

   imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
  }
 catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: how can I recycle,that images

Comment: if your are using Bitmap object then first check whether its null or not if its not null then call recycle on bitmap then assign null to it. for loadding images just use the inputstream and every time after using of input stream just flush() and close the input stream.

Comment: @user370305 - If you don't like the fact that my answer was accepted, please comment with a tag of the OP (@Jorge), otherwise he won't notice your comment.

Comment: @MByD - Before some time my answer was accepted thats why. I accept that your answer is also right. I don't have objection on it. I just want to know about it if there any rules or moderator for do it.

Comment: @user370305 - I have no problem with that at all, I just thought that the OP won't see your comment, as you commented to my answer, with no tagging for the OP. And the OP is the only one who controls what is the accepted answer, not any moderator.

Comment: @MByD -its ok. and sorry for my comment. I just want to know how the accepted answers flag are changed? its done by questioners or moderator also change it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't increase the memory size, but release each picture after using it (e.g. when you flip a page.)

Answer (score 0):

When the device/app is out of memory, there is no possibility to increase it. You cant get more memory than memory is available. Instead, try to release the older bitmaps from the memory. You can also call gc() to give the garbage collector a hint that its the right moment to "destroy" the older objects.
Also note, that there is a size limit of the bitmap you can load.

Check this out:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

interessting methods: inSampleSize, inPurgeable

Answer (score 0):

With SMS messages, you can download ChompSMS and increase the font size to fix your issue there.

Also, you setup a Shortcut, to a bookmark, to gmail through the browser so you can zoom in with the browser.

Other than those two options, I'm not too sure you have many more.

Maybe this is something JF or Haykuro can introduce in their builds? Although, I have no idea what that all consists of so don't hold me to it, or them to it.

[attendance tracking software](http://www.labortimetracker.com/features.cfm)